# datalevin db/id vs db/ident

Tags: clojure, datascript

I want to use [Datalevin](https://github.com/juji-io/datalevin) as a database for my app. The README mentions `:db/id` as the identifier of entities, and I see these do get an autoincremented integer value on insertion.

However, there are also multiple mentions of `:db/ident` in the source code, for example for [implicit constants](https://github.com/juji-io/datalevin/blob/735222d455f13ab1cbefbd8ded5680860f065c16/src/datalevin/constants.cljc#L25).

What are the purposes of the two keywords and what are the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:db/ident` are called [Entity
Identifiers](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/transactions/transactions.html#entity-identifiers)
in Datomic.

They are used to allow for easier "pointing" to other, well known
things; like an enum.  So you can have the enum values as datums, but
still be able to reference them via a keyword (no need to look them up
every time before using them).

E.g.

```clj
(def conn (d/create-conn "./tst" {})) 
  
(d/transact! conn  
             [{:db/id 1, :customer-type/name "Fictional", :db/ident :fictional}
              {:db/id 2, :customer/name "ACME", :customer/type :fictional}])   
  
(d/pull @conn                                                                                         
        [:db/id :customer/name {:customer/type [:db/id :customer-type/name]}]
        2)  
; ⇒ {:db/id 2, :customer/name "ACME", 
;    :customer/type {:db/id :fictional, 
;                    :customer-type/name "Fictional"}}
```